# UITextView firstRectForRange returns wrong frame

Tags: ios, objective-c

**Edit**

The simple solution is to move any frame calculations from `viewDidLoad` to `viewDidAppear:`

---

I'm having a difficult time getting the following code to work properly

The code returns the first frame for a given NSRange in a UITextView.

It works if there are no line breaks, but I get some strange behavior when I add line breaks in the UITextView.

```
@implementation UITextView (TextFrame)

- (CGRect)frameOfTextRange:(NSRange)range {
    UITextPosition *beginning = self.beginningOfDocument;
    UITextPosition *start = [self positionFromPosition:beginning offset:range.location];
    UITextPosition *end = [self positionFromPosition:start offset:range.length];
    UITextRange *textRange = [self textRangeFromPosition:start toPosition:end];
    CGRect rect = [self firstRectForRange:textRange];

    return [self convertRect:rect fromView:self.textInputView];
}

@end

@implementation DetailViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad 
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
   if (self.searchString) {
        CGRect rect = [self.textView frameOfTextRange:[self.textView.text rangeOfString:self.searchString]];
        ...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apparently it seems that `firstRectForRange:`is NOT working in `viewDidLoad`

Moving the calculations from `viewDidLoad`to `viewDidAppear:` **solved the problem**

**Old code**

```
- (void)viewDidLoad 
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    if (self.searchString) {
        CGRect rect = [self.textView frameOfTextRange:[self.textView.text rangeOfString:self.searchString]];
        [self.textView scrollRangeToVisible:[self.textView.text rangeOfString:self.searchString]];
        UIView *markerView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:rect];
        markerView.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0.810 green:0.735 blue:0.000 alpha:0.660];
        [self.textView addSubview:markerView];
        _searchString = nil;
    }
}
```

**New and working code**

```
- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];

    if (self.searchString) {
        CGRect rect = [self.textView frameOfTextRange:[self.textView.text rangeOfString:self.searchString]];
        [self.textView scrollRangeToVisible:[self.textView.text rangeOfString:self.searchString]];
        UIView *markerView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:rect];
        markerView.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0.810 green:0.735 blue:0.000 alpha:0.660];
        [self.textView addSubview:markerView];
        _searchString = nil;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 8):

I found the following solution to work. Instead of using `firstRectForRange:`, which only returns one rect, I use `selectionRectsForRange:`, and then iterate over all rects and use `CGRectUnion` to combine them.

```
- (CGRect)frameOfTextRange:(NSRange)range
{
   UITextPosition *beginning = self.beginningOfDocument;
   UITextPosition *start = [self positionFromPosition: beginning offset: range.location];
   UITextPosition *end = [self positionFromPosition: start offset: range.length];

   UITextRange *textRange = [self textRangeFromPosition: start toPosition: end];

   CGRect  rect = CGRectZero;

   NSArray *selectionRects = [self selectionRectsForRange: textRange];

   for (UITextSelectionRect *selectionRect in selectionRects)
   {
      rect = CGRectUnion(rect, selectionRect.rect);
   }

   return rect;
}
```

Comment: seems legit for optimizing it. Haven't tested, but would it make a giant rect or does it make smaller clips?

Comment: Since I'm using `CGRectUnion`, this would indeed make one giant rect. But you could of course also grab each `selectionRect.rect` and do with it what you'd like.

Comment: I like your solution, so take +1 :)

Answer (score 3):

You can force `self.textView` to ensure layout immediately with:

```
[self.textView.layoutManager ensureLayoutForTextContainer:self.textView.textContainer];
```

Placing that before your `frameOfTextRange:` call will gives you right rect.

Of course you can call that within your `frameOfTextRange:` method:

```
- (CGRect)frameOfTextRange:(NSRange)range {
    [self.layoutManager ensureLayoutForTextContainer:self.textContainer];
    ...
```

This makes `frameOfTextRange:` method can be safely called from anywhere.

Answer (score 2):

This works fine for me with line-breaks(`'\n'`) in old project.

```
@implementation UITextView (TextFrame)

- (CGRect)frameOfTextRange:(NSRange)range
{
    UITextPosition *beginning = self.beginningOfDocument;

    UITextPosition *start = [self positionFromPosition:beginning offset:range.location];
    UITextPosition *end = [self positionFromPosition:start offset:range.length];
    UITextRange *textRange = [self textRangeFromPosition:start toPosition:end];
    CGRect rect = [self firstRectForRange:textRange];  

    return [self convertRect:rect fromView:self.textInputView];
}

@end
```

Here is my `Swift` translation

```
extension UITextView {

    func frameOfTextRange(range:NSRange) -> CGRect {

        let beginning = self.beginningOfDocument;
        let start = self.positionFromPosition(beginning, offset: range.location)
        let end = self.positionFromPosition(start, offset: range.length)
        let textRange = self.textRangeFromPosition(start, toPosition: end)

        let rect = self.firstRectForRange(textRange)
        return self.convertRect(rect, fromView: self.textInputView)
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry it does exactly the same. Works fine for finding frames for words before a line break, but when I try to find the frame for a word after a line break, the frame is not correct

Comment: It wouldn't work in case I want to find the last character position and it's a new line. Tested on iOS 10.3 Simulator.

Answer (score 1):

`viewDidLoad:` is called right after a view is loaded from a nib or the `loadView` method. It's is not resized for the container it is being placed in until later.

If you were looking for the best place, it would seem to be the `-[UIViewController viewDidLayoutSubviews]` method:

```
- (void)viewDidLayoutSubviews
{
    if (self.searchString) 
    {
        CGRect rect = [self.textView frameOfTextRange:[self.textView.text rangeOfString:self.searchString]];
        [self.textView scrollRangeToVisible:[self.textView.text rangeOfString:self.searchString]];
        UIView *markerView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:rect];
        markerView.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0.810 green:0.735 blue:0.000 alpha:0.660];
        [self.textView addSubview:markerView];
        _searchString = nil;
    }
}
```

You would also probably want to add a property to hold 'marketView' so that if it was laid out again (in response to rotation or something else), that it could be relocated instead of adding a new view.

Answer (score 0):

Controllers' views in `viewDidLoad` have arbitrary, non-definitive frames as the parent view controllers available size, status bar status, etc., have not yet been applied.

The best place to do precise frame calculation is in `viewWillAppear`, that is when the loaded view has been added to the parent controllers/window view hierarchy and its `frame` is "definitive".

Answer (score 0):

The solution that worked for me in Swift is based on [Koen's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29577255/2982993) with one key difference. Instead of calculating the `UITextRange` based not the selected range I used [selectedTextRange](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitextinput/1614541-selectedtextrange) property instead. This property already returns `UITextRange` calculated for the selected text range.

Swift 5.3 (tested might work on lower versions):

```
import UIKit

extension UITextView {
    /**
     Returns selected text frame position
     */
    func frameOfSelectedTextRange() -> CGRect? {
        guard let selectedTextRange = self.selectedTextRange,
              !selectedTextRange.isEmpty else { return nil }
        let rects = self.selectionRects(for: selectedTextRange)
        
        let rect = rects.reduce(into: CGRect.zero) { (res: inout CGRect, next: UITextSelectionRect) in
            res = res.union(next.rect)
        }
        
        return rect
    }
}
```

**Note** [B.S's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25387441/2982993) uses `firstRectForRange` which returned to me the wrong frame position for my selected text.